# How add useState in React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am trying for add `useState` in test case with React Testing Library, but it is not working for me. My code is as follows. Depending on `isLoading` component will render. How do I add `isLoading` state in React test cases? I want to add `isLoading` as false as initial state in my test.

`edit-inspection.tsx`:

```
 const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
 useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);

   }, []);

 const renderComponent = () => {
 <div role="homepagedata">
  </div>;
 }
return isLoading ? <CircularIndeterminate /> : renderComponent();
```

My test case is:

```
  import EditInspection from '../edit-inspection';
  test('Add new quality inspection record', async () => { 
  render(<EditInspection />);
  expect(screen.getByRole('homepagedata'));
  });
```

Shows these error message

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "homepagedata"
```

Comment: Leaving aside that your expectation lacks an actual assertion and you shouldn't just invent your own "role", `setLoading` _is_ initially false, but then immediately set to true by the effect.

Comment: I didn't add full code,there is lot of conditions in the same file,,,just i added these only.depends on differect api isloading will become true or false,,,

Answer (score 0):

By your comment, it seems you have lots of conditioning and logic in your react component. Here is a possible solution to test the logic separate from the presentational component.

Extract all your logic in a separate hook e.g. `useCustomRenderingCondtion` which has all react hooks and your conditioning parts. Then test that hook with [react-hooks-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library).

#### workflow

```
// container (smart, stateful, logical) component
const EditInspector = () => {
  const isLoading = useCustomRenderingCondtion()
  return <EditInspectorPresentational isLoading={isLoading} />
}

// presenatational (dummy, stateless) component 
const EditInspectorPresentational = ({ isLoading }) => {
   const renderComponent = () => {
     return <div role="homepagedata"></div>
  }
   
  return isLoading ? <CircularIndeterminate /> : renderComponent();
}
```

1. Test `useCustomRenderingCondtion` with react-hooks-testing-library.
2. Test EditInspectorPresentational with React Testing Library or any other thing.